# Return a System.Window.Point type value on TagetNullValue in Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to know that how can I return a System.Window.Point type of value in TagetNullValue of my binding. This binding has no converter and just I would like to use a TagetNullValue which will return typeof System.Window.Point value. Thank you!

My binding error says that 'Can not find sourcefor binding with referece 'blablacustomcontrol','AncestorLevel='1'. BindingExprssion:Path=blablaproperty;DataItem=null;target element is 'blabla'; target property is'blablapoperty' (type 'Point')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`BindingBase.FallbackValue` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not return anything to the user. Furthermore, the user does not specify the type of the `FallbackValue` value. On the linked page, `FallbackValue` is described as:

> An attribute or object element value of the same type as the target property. ...  The target property type will therefore influence which syntax you use for the value of the FallbackValue property.

---

UPDATE >>>

You *seem* to be very confused about data `Binding`. First, you asked about `FallbackValue` and then you changed that to `TargetNullValue`, but neither of those are your problem. Your error *clearly* states that it *cannot find the source for binding...*... surely you should address that instead?

I'd advise you to take a good look at the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN and then come back and ask a new question based on your new found knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyView"
 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=WindowsBase">

<Binding Blah>
    <Binding.FallbackValue>                             
        <sys:Point X="10" Y="10"/>
    </Binding.FallbackValue>
</Binding>
```

Comment: Why `System.Drawing.Point`? OP is clearly asking for `System.Windows.Point`.

Comment: @Clemens because my binded property type is System.Windows.Point.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. My binding error says that 'Can not find sourcefor binding with referece 'blablacustomcontrol','AncestorLevel='1'. BindingExprssion:Path=blablaproperty;DataItem=null;target element is 'blabla'; target property is'blablapoperty' (type 'Point')